# jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have a problem with Trent Richardson's Date and Time picker ([link](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)). The time picker just does now pops-out. Not working entirely.

My code:

jQuery includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://mydomain.org/folder/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

And for the call for function I have:

```
<script>
$('#datumodhoda').datetimepicker({
timeFormat: "h:m t",
ampm: true
});
</script>
```

What could be wrong? The other jquery calls working correctly. The path to the new addon is correct, the browser loads it (checked with firebug).

Having problems with this for over a week now.

Would be very happy if someone helps me, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code inside a document.ready function?

Comment: If your input field have  `class="hasDatepicker"`. try by removing it. I figure out that this class added by its js, but if we already put it with html it will not work.

Comment: @wirey yes, stil not working, *Andrew- i do not understand what do you mean, *Yigrah- i saw this in other questions here and tried but still no luck

Comment: Can you post your html code for input control. or can create a jsfiddle

Comment: <input type="text" name="datumodhoda" value="" id="datumodhoda" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-use-title-as-watermark watermark" size="40" title="Datum in čas odhoda">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version seems to be broken. Check out [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130509002354/http://timjames.me/themes/timjames.me/scripts/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker.js) version. Worked for me.

*The original link is dead. The current one uses WayBackMachine.*